# I am Unable to access WP admin

Tags: plugins

I am unable to access my WP admin.

Showing an Error message:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home2/tosaleco/public_html/wp-content/plugins/p3-profiler/p3-profiler.php on line 50

Here is the line 50

```
if ( is_admin() && 'admin-ajax.php' == end( explode( '/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) ) ) {
```

I had nil knowledge about PHP. Please let me know what changes in that line will give me access to my WP admin.

Will be waiting for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the WP Admin, but as you are directed and you already is there, the plugin `p3-profiler`.

If you have the cpanel access, just get into the `wp-content/plugins/` folder and **move** the folder `p3-profiler` on step up (so that it would go to the `wp-content/` folder, and out of the `/plugins` folder.

I think then you can get into your wp-admin without any hassle.

**Additional:** for plugin related issues, please contact with the plugin author directly by their support forum or wordpress.org support forum to get the direct reply from the plugin author, and that would be the best.

Hope that helps.